# extracting attribute value from html

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.nepalstock.com.np/marketdepthofcompany/238")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
value_select = soup.select_one("select.form-control")
for val in value_select.find("option")[1:]:
    n = val['value']
    print (n)
```

Why does the above code prints out text from the html not the attribute value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `find` returns a single tag, you need `find_all`:

```
for val in value_select.find_all("option")[1:]:
    n = val['value']
    print (n)
```

Or use a css selector to skip the first option:

```
for val in value_select.select("option + option"):
```

Both work the same:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: r = requests.get("http://www.nepalstock.com.np/marketdepthofcompany/238")

In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

In [5]: value_select = soup.select_one("select.form-control")

In [6]: for val in value_select.find_all("option")[1:]:
   ...:         n = val['value']
   ...:         print (n)
   ...:     
ACEDBL
ACEDPO
ADBL
AHPC
ALDBL
ALDBLP
ALICL
ALICLP
APEX
APEXPO
API
ARDBL
ARDBLP
ARUN
ARUNPO
AVU
BARUN
BBBLNP
...................................

In [7]: for val in value_select.select("option + option"):
   ...:         n = val['value']
   ...:         print (n)
   ...:     
ACEDBL
ACEDPO
ADBL
AHPC
ALDBL
ALDBLP
ALICL
ALICLP
APEX
APEXPO
API
ARDBL
ARDBLP
ARUN
ARUNPO
AVU
BARUN
BBBLNP
..........................
```

To get the options where the values are ints, select the id `StockSymbol_Select2`, there are more than one `select.form-control` so you need to specify which one exactly:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.nepalstock.com.np/marketdepthofcompany/238")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
value_select = soup.select_one("#StockSymbol_Select2")
for val in value_select.select("option + option"):
    print (val["value"])
```

That will give you what you want:

```
In [13]: value_select = soup.select_one("#StockSymbol_Select2")

In [14]: for val in value_select.select("option + option"):
   ....:         print (val["value"])
   ....:     
216
294
397
360
406
660
385
599
262
666
697
..............................
```

Comment: Tried both still doesn't work. 

<option value="216">ACEDBL</option> the html follows this structure and only prints out the AECDBL whereas I want 216.

Comment: I ran the code and both worked fine so you must be doing something wrong

Comment: Sorry if i put the question wrong. The html follows following structure. 
<option value="216">ACEDBL</option> From this I want to extract the "216" not ACEDBL.

Comment: Thank you. Totally went over my head.